# For which values is this a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n\ge0$. $P^n$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ s.t. it is the set of all polynomials with degree $\le n$ and coefficients in $\Bbb R$.

Consider $W_t=\{f \in P^n : f(1)=t\}$ where $t \in \Bbb R$.

For what values of $t$ is $W_t$ a subspace of $P^n$?

Without giving me the answer, how do I read this question? I'm not sure how to show for which elements $t$ that $W_t$ fulfills the axioms for a subspace because I can't properly interpret what it means by $f(1)=t$. For example: would showing that $f_a(1)+f_b(1)=2t$ (where $f_a(1)=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$ and $f_b(1)=b_1+b_2+...+b_n$)  prove closure under addition?

Comment: A subspace must always contain the zero vector. What must $t$ be in order for the zero vector of $P^n$ to lie in $W_t$?

Comment: But what exactly is the zero vector of $P^n$?

Comment: Can you think of a polynomial $p_0$ such that $p_0+p=p$ for all other polynomials in $P^n$?

Comment: Work with the definition: it's the polynomial $0$ such that $P + 0 = P$ for all polynomials $P$. Can you see what it is?

Comment: A polynomial $P_a=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n$ s.t. $a_0,a_1,...,a_n=0$?

Comment: Precisely. We normally call such a polynomial the 'zero polynomial' and in your vector space it is the zero vector as you should be able to prove.

Comment: @Barbara: I won’t roll it back, but that edit should have been a comment suggesting that the OP make the change; it’s really up to the OP to make substantive changes (and he’s likely to learn more that way as well). (I was in the process of rejecting it when someone approved it ahead of me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the following:

1. $0\in W_t$
2. $\lambda\in\Bbb R,\,f,g\in W_t \implies f+\lambda g\in W_t$.

Now 1. reduces the possible $t$'s, and check 2. for that one.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse image of a vector subspace under a linear map is linear.  Can you use this principle?

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't done linear maps yet, we can only solve this using the axioms.